# Slice array then merg the contents to form single arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

My array result returns Many different arrays, I want to slice the array based on a number x, then combine the results to give me one full outcome.. for example, say the array is of size 8 i want to slice it down to 2 size 4's then combine the array items to form two final arrays...

My code:

```
$number = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount(); //0 - nth in this case n=2

for ($i = 0; $i <= $number - 1; $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet_name = $objWorksheet->getTitle();
    $value = $objWorksheet->getCell('C19')->getValue();
    $value2 = $this->getTestNumberC($value); //get db row count and data for each row

    if (!empty($value) && (int) $value == $value2[0]->wk_no) {
        for($j=0;$j<count($value2);$j++){
            $diss_array = array(
                'component' => $sheet_name,
                $value2[$j]->parameter => $objWorksheet->getCell($value2[$j]->cell)->getFormattedValue()
            );
            // $new = array_slice($diss_array,0,3);
            print "<pre>";
            print_r($diss_array);
            print "</pre>";
        } else if(/*some condition*/){
    }else{
   }
}



function getTestNumberC($v){
    return $this->db->where('wk_no',$v)->get('generic_worksheet')->result();
}
```

What I have

```
Array
(
    [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION
    [Average] => 102.52
)

Array
(
    [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION
    [RSD] => 0.26%
)

Array
(
    [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION
    [n] => 3
)

Array
(
    [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION (2)
    [Average] => 135.00
)

Array
(
    [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION (2)
    [RSD] => 0.19%
)

Array
(
    [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION (2)
    [n] => 3
)
```

What i want to do is have something like this

```
 Array
    (
        [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION
        [Average] => 102.52
        [RSD] => 0.26%
        [n] => 3
    )

 Array
    (
        [component] => eSORAL 40 iNJECTION (2)
        [Average] => 135.00
        [RSD] => 0.19%
        [n] => 3
    )
```

I have tried to slice with array_slice($array,0,3) Outcome is the same. Any suggestions!

Comment: Do you have the PHP code you've used to get these arrays? Are they separate variables or is it an array of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think I understand what you're trying to do here. Try this:

```
// 0 - nth in this case n=2
$number       = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();
$newDissArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $number - 1; $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet_name   = $objWorksheet->getTitle();
    $value        = $objWorksheet->getCell('C19')->getValue();
    //get db row count and data for each row
    $value2       = $this->getTestNumberC($value);

    if (!empty($value) && (int) $value == $value2[0]->wk_no) {
        for ($j=0; $j < count($value2); $j++) {
            // as we loop through we use the sheet name as a key to
            // build up an associative array of all the components
            if (!isset($newDissArray[$sheet_name])) {
                $newDissArray[$sheet_name] = array(
                    'component' => $sheet_name
                );
            }

            $newDissArray[$sheet_name][$value2[$j]->parameter]
                = $objWorksheet->getCell($value2[$j]->cell)->getFormattedValue();
        }

        // $newDissArray is at this point an associative array
        // so we need to strip it down to values only
        $newDissArray = array_values($newDissArray);
    }
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($newDissArray);
print "</pre>";


function getTestNumberC($v){
    return $this->db->where('wk_no',$v)->get('generic_worksheet')->result();
}
```

Comment: All part of the service :-)

Comment: I have noticed something else Kevin, since the condition is else if, I wanted to get the results within the if, unlike outside it, When i do that it creates two different arrays, not one with two elements... could you be knowing the reason why, i am also looking to see what i am missing!

Comment: So is there an `if/else` surrounding this bit of code? In that case, move the `$newDissArray = array();` and the `print`s outside of the scope of that `if/else`

Comment: Yes that code is surrounded with the if/else so that its only executed when the values match and stored in the database, and if the values does not match the condition executes another set of instructions. Hope you understand

Comment: I think I get it. I presume the `if/else` is within a loop as well and you really just want a single array when the loop is complete? If so, move the `$newDissArray = array();` to before the loop and the `print`s to after the loop.

Comment: Okey, Let me try that, the if else is also within the outer loop, Let me do that, in case i run into a bug, I will hope for your more efficient services :)

Answer (score 0):

You know there are only two values per array so you could do it with a for loop!

```
$array1 = array('component' => 'eSORAL 40 iNJECTION', 'Average' => '102.52');
$array2 = array('component' => 'eSORAL 40 iNJECTION', 'RSD' => '0.26%');
$array2 = array('component' => 'eSORAL 40 iNJECTION', 'n' => '3');
$combine = array();

for($i = 0, $i < 2; $++) {
    $combine = array(
         'component' => $array1['component'],
         'Average' => $array1['Average'],
         'RSD' => $array2['RSD'],
         'n' => $array3['n'],
    );
}

print_r($combine);
```